# Plot horizontally from two columns

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

my data looks like this

```
1 5 0.5
1 7 0.4
1 9 1.6
2 1 2.1
2 2 1.9
2 3 0
2 10 0.6
3 3 0.8
3 15 0.5
4 1 0.2
4 2 0.1
4 5 0.4
```

in which col 1 represents the section (1...4), col 2 the x calue and xol 3 the y value. Think about the first columns as different trails. I would like to plot them horizontally next to each other and in a single plot. So not using layout or something . I know that every trail as has a specific x axis range ..trail 1 from 0 to 10, tail 2 from 0 to 15, trail 3 from 0 to 20 and trail 4 from 1 to 40. Then how can i plot then horizontally next to each other in a plot?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Would it be enough to color points on an xy scatter by the column 1 value? Or do you care more about displaying the data in column 2 or 3, such that it becomes a simple horizontal barplot?

Comment: just a simple dot plot but horizontal

Comment: in the plot you are imagining, what are your x and y axes? I imagine your x axis is either the 2nd or 3rd collumn. is your y axis the first collumn?